# What are the security implications of using a web font hosted by a 3rd party provider?

Tags: css, security, fonts, webfonts

What are the security implications of using a web font hosted by a 3rd party provider, such as Google or Adobe?

Comment: This question belongs on security.stackexchange.com

Comment: If you're certain that's the case, please start work on moving the 20,000+ questions tagged security from Stack Overflow to the Security Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google Fonts offers 3 methods of including their fonts on your page: through the `link` element, through the CSS `@import` statement and through external JavaScript.

There should be no security problems if you include your stylesheet using the `link` element with a `type` attribute set to "text/css" or through the css `@import` statement; the browser would only attempt to read this as CSS and ignore anything which is invalid.

There would be potential security risks in including the fonts through external JavaScript, but this all boils down to trust; do you trust Google or Adobe to host JavaScript for you?

Comment: Thanks James. In addition, the providers would be able to track the IP of your site's visitors, and any other information exposed by your browser such as user-agent. For users logged into Google, they may have enough information to uniquely identify you visiting a site that uses one of their web fonts.

Comment: You mentioned that the JS method has potential security risks.  What about security/privacy risk when including the font as link/import? Doesn't the browser then trust the domain that the font came from and therefore javascript could be run from the font domain or data sent to the font domain?  I am not sure if the link/import methods add the font domain to the list of trusted JS domains.